# About the ICA Suffix in Some Morisawa Fonts

Tags: fonts, japanese

The Japanese type foundry Morisawa offers some typefaces whose names end with the suffix "ICA". Clearly, it is not a foundry name suffix. Also, judging from the fact that most (I think) of those fonts are school-named and brush-styled, I conjecture that it has something to do with educational matters.

Examples of said fonts are:

- 教科書ICA (Kyōkasho ICA)
- 学参 教科書ICA (Gakusan kyōkasho ICA)
- 筆順ICA (Hitsujun ICA) - this is a font for learning stroke order.

Do anyone know about the meaning of the suffix?

Comment: It means "Internal Cryptic Acronym".

Comment: I'm _seriously_ considering that, @Earthliŋ! XD
Some info that appears on the Kyoukasho ICA page, from the Morisawa site: "The letter shapes conform to [Ministry of Education, Culture, Sports, Science and Technology](http://www.mext.go.jp/)'s curriculum guidelines of Elementary School Courses of Study..."